# Update selected columns containing 0 with NULL

Tags: postgresql, update, dynamic-sql, null

I want to update all columns named with suffix '[]' in the table `geochem` if they have zeros (0) with NULL.

This query returns all relevant column names:

```
select c.COLUMN_NAME 
  from information_schema.COLUMNS as c 
 where c.TABLE_NAME = 'geochem' 
   and c.COLUMN_NAME like '%\[%\]'
```

Example of results:

[image: Result]

Then update values in these columns e.g. column `SiO2[%{wt}]`

```
UPDATE geochem
SET "SiO2[%{wt}]" = NULL
WHERE "SiO2[%{wt}]" = 0;
```

How can I combine these queries to update all columns returned by Q1, instead of updating column by column manually?

Comment: I'd recommend you to normalize the structure to (geochem_entity_id, formula, value). *How can I combine the queries above* Dynamic SQL may solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist ask yourself if a table structure with a single value column like suggested by [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) in the comments wouldn't be more practical.

While stuck with your current design, you need **dynamic SQL** to target a dynamic set of columns. But first, optimize the command(s).

Every `UPDATE` writes a new row version for every row that is not excluded from the `UPDATE`. Your approach writes another new row version for every single column.

Combine all of these:

```
UPDATE geochem
SET    "SiO2[%{wt}]" = NULL
WHERE  "SiO2[%{wt}]" = 0;

UPDATE geochem
SET    "TiO2[%{wt}]" = NULL
WHERE  "TiO2[%{wt}]" = 0;

-- more?
```

... into a single `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE geochem
SET    "SiO2[%{wt}]" = NULLIF("SiO2[%{wt}]", 0)
,      "TiO2[%{wt}]" = NULLIF("TiO2[%{wt}]", 0)
 -- more?
WHERE  0 = ANY ("SiO2[%{wt}]", "TiO2[%{wt}]");  -- more?
```

Note the adapted `WHERE` clause to check if *any* of the target columns holds *0*. [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) per column only nullifies if it is *0*.

To do this dynamically, concatenate the statement safely, then execute:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql
          'UPDATE public.geochem
SET    '
       || string_agg(format('%1$s = NULLIF(%1$s, 0)', c.col), E'\n,      ')
       || E'\nWHERE  0 = ANY ('
       || string_agg(c.col, ', ')
       || ');'
   FROM  (
      SELECT quote_ident(c.column_name) AS col  -- ! to be safe
      FROM   information_schema.columns AS c
      WHERE  c.table_name = 'geochem'
      AND    c.table_schema = 'public'  -- ! to be safe
      AND    c.column_name LIKE '%\[%\]'
      ) c;
      
   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      RAISE WARNING 'Did not find any matching columns!';
   ELSE
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;
      -- EXECUTE _sql  -- uncomment to actually execute
   END IF;
END
$do$
```

I added a child-safety device, so this only raises a notice with the statement to execute. Un-comment the `EXECUTE` line (and comment the `RAISE NOTICE` line) to execute it immediately.